# How can i get input onchange event to call a c# method and pass a value into it asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, onchange

[Click Here to see What the Page Cart.aspx looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Jg9A.png) in page Cart.aspx i have a input quantity inside a repeater and i need to get id of the product , and call a c# method to update the quantity in cart table   every time the value changes

```
 <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1"  DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="repeater1_ItemCommand">
                                 <ItemTemplate>
    <div class="items">
                                <div class="product">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-3" style="left: 19px;top: 31px;">
                                            <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block image" src='<%# Eval("ProductImageLink").ToString().Replace("\\", "/") %>'>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-md-8">
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <div class="row">
                                                    <div class="col-md-5 product-name">
                                                        <div class="product-name">
                                                            <a href="<%#"ProductDetails.aspx?ThisId="+ Eval("ProductID")%>"> <%#Eval("ProductName")%></a>
                                                            <div class="product-info">
                                                                <div> Description : <span class="value"> <%#Eval("ProductDescription")%> </span></div>
                                                                <div> Category :  <span class="value"> <%#Eval("ProductType")%></span></div>
                                                                <%-- <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>'  runat="server" ID="ProducttID" />--%>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-4 quantity">
                                                        <label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
                                                        <%--i need the onchange to call a c# method and give it the product id  as a parameter --%>
                                                         <asp:Label Text='<%#Eval("ProductID")%>' runat="server" ID="ProductID" />
                                                         <input id="quantity" type="number" value='<%# Eval("Quantity")%>'  class="form-control quantity-input" runat="server"  min="1" max='<%# Eval("Stock")%>'/>
                                                         

    
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-3 price" style="margin-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px;padding-left: 0px;">
                                                        <span><%#Eval("ProductPrice")%>$</span>
                                                         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Remove" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"  CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument = '<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ProductID")%>' />
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            
                            
                            </div>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: how about using a asp.net control like TextBox instead of a pure client side input element and attach a server side event handler?

Comment: haven"t thought of that thank you i will try it

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript  but idk how you'd be able to get the product id it will just call the c# method

Comment: Yea i have already tried that but if i want to do that the method should be static and i won't be able to access the repeater elements or any control at all, and i also tried to take the value and put it in the javascript function but it only takes the first product id it  doesn't get updated when i wanna change other product quantity